# How to obtain actual Text area (baseline) in Word VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm currently developing a Word Add-in with VSTO.
I understand Window.GetPoint is very useful to detect the area of a specified Range.

We can also get an actual text area by subtracting Paragraph.SpaceAfter area (and Paragraph.SpaceBefore) from Rect obtained with GetPoint as illustrated below.

[image]

Problems:
When Paragraph.SpaceAfterAuto is set as True, SpaceAfter number does not represent the actual space. How can we get the actual text area when Paragraph.SpaceAfterAuto == True?